# Image of God denotes perfection and holiness? Does Murder destroys the likeness of God in the self or the victim?

Tags: genesis-bereishith, adam, kedusha-holiness

Is there any commentary which details about the object of the likeness of God? Is the murderer destroys his own perfection (divine likeness) or he is punished for destroying the innocent/perfect victim, or both? In other words, has the divine likeness described as man's original and intended perfection, holiness in which Adam was created? Are sinners loses the divine likeness by their imperfection?

> Rashi- Gen 9:6
> באדם דמו ישפך BY MAN SHALL HIS BLOOD BE SHED — If there are witnesses you kill him. Why? Because in the image of God [made He man] and he has destroyed the Divine image (Genesis Rabbah 34:14)

> [Legends of the Jews](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=adam%20image%20god&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) 1:3:8
> And still another consequence of the sin of idolatry was that the countenances of the men of the following generations were no longer in the likeness and image of God, as the countenances of Adam, Seth.
> The Legends of the Jews by Louis Ginzberg [1909]

Comment: There are sources to the effect that sin destroys the divine image of the sinner. However the specific reference to it in the context of murder and no other sin can only mean that of the victim

Answer (score 1):

In the sefer דרך פקודך (not on Sefaria) which is organized by Mitzvot - it is listed under the Mitzva of not creating an object in the form of a Man that:

All Aveiras transform Man's image into an imitation of the Man's image. This is why its forbidden to create an object in the image of a Man because it is an imitation rather than the precise image which is only created through procreation. The concept of imitation is referred to often as Eishet Znunim. It is also sometimes called Adam Bliyal. This stems from the more general idea that the entire Klipa is an imitation of קדושה.